# Regular expression to match 10-14 digits

Tags: asp.net, regex

I am using regular expressions for matching only digits, minimum 10 digits, maximum 14. I tried:

```
^[0-9]
```

Comment: Just in case you use that as a integer later... take care of leading zeros!

Comment: Please bookmark http://www.regularexpressions.info too, while you're at it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I'd give:

```
^\d{10,14}$
```

a shot.

I also like to offer extra solutions for RE engines that don't support all that PCRE stuff so, in a pinch, you could use:

```
^[0-9]{10,14}$
```

If you're RE engine is so primitive that it doesn't even allow specific repetitions, you'd have to revert to either some ugly hack like fully specifying the number of digits with alternate REs for 10 to 14 or, easier, just checking for:

```
^[0-9]*$
```

and ensuring the length was between 10 and 14.

But that won't be needed for this case (ASP.NET).

Comment: Really nice one, the first one helped me also :) +1

Answer (score 7):

```
^\d{10,14}$
```

#### regular-expressions.info

- [Character Classes or Character Sets](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)

  > `\d` is short for `[0-9]`
- [Limiting Repetition](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)

  > The syntax is `{min,max}`, where `min` is a positive integer number indicating the minimum number of matches, and `max` is an integer equal to or greater than `min` indicating the maximum number of matches.

---

The limited repetition syntax also allows these:

```
^\d{10,}$ // match at least 10 digits
^\d{13}$  // match exactly 13 digits
```

Answer (score 4):

try this

```
@"^\d{10,14}$"
```

\d -  matches a character that is a digit

This will help you

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, this should work:

```
\d{10,14}
```

Note: 
As noted in the other answer.. `^\d{10,14}$` to match the entire input